# What should be the structure of ini files to create an .rmskin package from multiple software used

Tags: rainmeter, windows-themes, uxtheme, theme-customizer

On my windows 10 pc I utilize ux theme patcher, startallback, startisback, 7tsp with ivon an shell themes, msstyles themes, rainmeter, mnmIUI, and JaxCore all together simultaneously to create high personalized 32 layers and interactive desktop wallpaper environments. JAXCORE is quintessential with the modlular widgets it loads into rainmeter. Ideally I'd like to writ each completed project to a single Rmskin file for simple installation and maybe even start my own digital storefront for completed theme packages. I will try to attach an example or at least a still image of one. [GIF EXAMPLE OF FINISHE DESKTOP NOT ENOUGH SPACE IN FILESIZE TO SHOW ALL FEATURES ONLY BASIC LOOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJhZa.gif)

I tried copying ini file information from each individual element nd assembling my own package, but it fales to load does not seem to carry over with it the necessary files and resources necessary to use the skin. I've never done this before so I'm not altogether familiar with concepts behind ini files.